# Some newbie issue with counting in PHP

Tags: php

Please tell me, what am I doing wrong and how should I fix this.

I'm trying to make a simple counter, that will count on each visiting(the page) plus 1 and will stop when the number is 5. But this doesn't work - it return the same number each time.

```
$x = 1;

while($x <= 5) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x = $x++;
    break;
}
```

Comment: use this in loop body `echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x++;`

Comment: tell us; is this for something you want to echo / write to a file and show an incremental number?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, basically each page view is new. To retain the count of previous views you'll need to do sessions/cookies.

Comment: yes Fred, probably... I just didn't know I should store it in the file first... Thought it can handle it somehow :) I'll try to figure out how to solve this then

Comment: @mysellf My "Spidey sense" told me so ;-) well, you have answers below. Given what you originally posted, writing to a file would really be considered as a separate question ;-) However, did you consider using a database for this instead of writing to a file? It's an option.

Comment: @mysellf I left [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793954/some-newbie-issue-with-counting-in-php#comment64958828_38794129) under RamRaider's answer; you should probably rethink this.

Comment: Yes, I will go investigate this a little bit further :) But this is only for learning and I was just thinking of some statistics... Thank you

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice about accepting the answer, lol  Will do, Captain @Fred -ii- ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you need to use a session variable - chance are I have misunderstood though.

```
session_start();

$name='counter';
$max=5;

if( !isset( $_SESSION[$name] ) ) $_SESSION[$name]=0;
if( $_SESSION[$name] <= $max ) $_SESSION[$name]++;

echo 'Page visits: '.$_SESSION[$name];
```

Comment: Thank you. But session as I understand not going to keep the number and on the new start it will be restarted. Should I keep this then in the file or DB? I don't know both ways, but I would like to go with the fastest in term of  overall performance

Comment: If you close the browser and return hoping to find the same number as when you left then sessions are not the right choice, cookie might be a better option

Comment: Yeah but cookies on client-side can always be deleted @RamRaider I'd go with a DB. However a db has its limitations (pros and cons) as does cookies/sessions/writing to a file. Should they limit users to a maximum of 5 and have no way to reset it, then the end-user stands at being locked out. Limiting to a certain number IMHO opinion would be a bad idea; this comment for the OP of course. The cookies thing; for you and the OP ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You've got 3 problems.

1. You have a `break`, which terminates the loop
2. `$x++;` is a standalone statement. You don't need to set `$x` to it
3. The counter will reset between calls. PHP doesn't know if this is your first or 40th time. So you will need to store this somewhere (i.e. a database or session) if you want to retain it

Try this

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['visit'])) $_SESSION['visit'] = 1;

if($_SESSION['visit'] < 5) $_SESSION['visit']++;
```

Comment: True, however I think their question goes further. Your solution will show every iteration, rather than what I think they want as being 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 etc. It's probably for a file too. Edit: My comment was in regards to the original post here http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38794049/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I missed the call between pages. Changed it to a session

Comment: What you posted in the edit is exactly what came to my mind ;-) but... the OP's question's a tad too unclear for moi.

Comment: Lol, I was editing the script when you posted it. What do you want to do exactly? You want to print the variable in the webpage or you want to store it in a database por statistics or so? If you just want to print it you can use the session variables, but if you want to save it just put it in a database

Comment: [Seems I was right on my first comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793954/some-newbie-issue-with-counting-in-php#comment64958533_38793954) and the [question asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793954/some-newbie-issue-with-counting-in-php#comment64958412_38793954) to the OP ;-)

Comment: I want it for statistics :) But I think DB will be slower than storing this in file, right? ...just googling now about it. And thank you too, Machavity

Comment: @mysellf *"But I think DB will be slower than storing this in file"* - Not really, unless you've got gahzillions of hits; sure. However the performance would be hardly felt. Yet, the choice is yours. You can go with one or the other, or even both and run a benchmark. Using files though, you'd need to make sure filelocking is in place.

Comment: @Fred -ii- And I was already achieving my ninja skills of writing and reading in the file. But tell me, what do you exactly mean by "fileblocking"? Are there some ways to ensure in terms of security the file won't be read from other source than my *.php file?

Comment: @mysellf filelocking means that no 2 (or more) instances can be written at the same time when it gets written to. Most hosted systems have that setting on by default, but it's best to read up on the subject http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: @Fred -ii-, Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes... the `fclose`... I know that! :) @Fred -ii-

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, values of variables **are not preserved between executions of the script**. Each time a user visits this page, `$x` is going to be 1.

Your script will get executed from the very beginning each time the page is requested. It will define `$x` to be one, display its value (which will be `1` at this point), increment it and then stop, since you put `break` at the end of the `while` loop body. Even if you remove `break` all you're going to accomplish is this counter being displayed 5 times *on the same page* with values 1 to 5.

The question of how you should "fix" this is too broad to be answered in any detail. So here are several vague options for you too consider:

- Store this value in a file on the server. Read it each time the script executes, increment it, store it back at the end.
- Store this value in a database. Read it each time... (ditto)
- Store this value in a cookie or make it a session variable. This way you will be able to count visits *per user*.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this